# How to get/print the name/identifier of an array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

Imagine we have two arrays:

```
int[] arrayOne = new int[] {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};

int[] arrayTwo = new int[] {60, 70, 80, 90, 100};
```

and we have a method to print members of those arrays and before we print the elements in arrays we want to print the name of the array:

```
void printNumbers(int[] arr){

    Console.WriteLine("Numbers in " + arrayName + ":");

    foreach(int num in arr){

    Console.WriteLine(num);
    }
}
```

What we should replace 'arrayName' with to have the name of the array printed before printing the elements inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean by `the name of the array` the variables name?

In that case you can just use `nameof()`.

```cs
void printNumbers(int[] arr, string arrayName)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Numbers in " + arrayName + ":");

    foreach(int num in arr){
        Console.WriteLine(num);
    }
}

void Main()
{
    int[] arrayOne = new int[] {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};

    int[] arrayTwo = new int[] {60, 70, 80, 90, 100};

    printNumbers(arrayOne, nameof(arrayOne));
    printNumbers(arrayTwo, nameof(arrayTwo));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `nameof`:

```
Console.WriteLine(nameof(arrayOne));
```

So in your code:

```
void printNumbers(int[] arr)
{

    Console.WriteLine($"Numbers in { nameof(arr) } :");

    foreach(int num in arr){

        Console.WriteLine(num);
    }
}
```